# Titanium modules importing error

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-studio

i am new into Titanium appcelarator IDE and upon running a project after importing modules, i get the following error. I have attached screenshots of my project. any help would be greatly appreciated !

```
[WARN] :   Could not find a valid Titanium module id=ti.paint version=latest platform=android deploy-type=development
[WARN] :   Could not find a valid Titanium module id=com.rkam.swiperefreshlayout version=latest platform=android deploy-type=development
[WARN] :   Could not find a valid Titanium module id=ti.inappbilling version=latest platform=android deploy-type=development
[WARN] :   Could not find a valid Titanium module id=com.cameraandroid version=latest platform=android deploy-type=development
[ERROR] :  Could not find all required Titanium Modules:
[ERROR] :     id: ti.paint   version: latest     platform: android   deploy-type: development
[ERROR] :     id: com.rkam.swiperefreshlayout    version: latest     platform: android   deploy-type: development
[ERROR] :     id: ti.inappbilling    version: latest     platform: android   deploy-type: development
[ERROR] :     id: com.cameraandroid  version: latest     platform: android   deploy-type: development
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The module must be in app/modules/android/ and app/modules/iphone

[image: titanium project folder organization]

Comment: is that i have to just extract the downloaded module and added it in the modules folder? @genoc sb

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Gittio, you can find modules and installing commands there. No need to do everything your self, just paste a command and hit enter. CLI will install it into the right folder straight away.